# Rails nested form dynamic div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my Rails App I am using a nested form and in my controller I have a loop which looks like this:

```
2.times do
  practice = @team.practices.build
end
```

In my nested form I create a select field with the following code:

```
<%= f.select :day, Practice.days.keys.to_a, {}, {class: 'form-control'} %>
```

which gets the id: "team_practices_attributes_0_day". This is for the first practice. The second practice shower receives this id: "team_practices_attributes_1_day"

Now I want to use the variable (0, 1) in my other ids for some jQuery. Is there a way to access this number in a form?

Comment: Are you wanting to add the variable to the select answer or to the select itself?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by the context of your `2.times` loop (is practice referenced on the form?) Is that where the two selects are built?). So, I'm not sure if you want this on the select helper or in the answers. But a [data attribute](https://api.jquery.com/data/) is an easy way to access data from any element.

You can add data attributes to the a select helper as part of the HTML options.

```
<%= f.select :day, Practice.days.keys.to_a, {}, {class: 'form-control', data-id: practice.id} %>
```

And then access them by calling the attribute name after `data` in jQuery. Note, you might want to add a specific class to query against.

```
var id = $('.form-control').data("id");
```

Comment: I have this loop in my controller to have 2 forms for my practices in the team form. Unfortunately practice does not have a id at this point.
Actually I just need to access any id I can pass to these fields to identify them via javascript.